# Xpath strange behavior - not matching text nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

While doing such things

```
foreach ($xpath->query('.//tpl-static', $domTemplateContainer) as $domStatic) {
    /* ... */
    $domStatic->parentNode->removeChild($domStatic);
}
```

All seems to work fine.

But when dealing with xml-comments and more importantly - text nodes it fails to work as intended:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('.//text()[normalize-space() = ""]', $domDocumentFragment) as $domNode) {
    $domNode->parentNode->removeChild($domNode);
}
```

some text nodes are just not selected but some are. I could not find logic behind this. Predicate does not matter. 
But I also found following query works fine:`./descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]`

Why does `.//` only work for element nodes but not for text nodes? Is it libxml/php bug or something to be reported or I've missed something?

**ADDITION:**

Complete example (adapted from complex project):

```
$xml = '
<tpl-static>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/icon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/html5reset-1.6.1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css" />
    <script src="/static/js/underscore.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/static/js/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/js/jquery.magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/templates/dealers-page-includes/page-includes.js"></script>
</tpl-static>
<br/>

';

$domDocument = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$domDocumentFragment = $domDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$domDocumentFragment->appendXml($xml);

$templateName = 'test';
//$it = $this;
$adoptTemplate = function($domTemplateContainer) use (&$adoptTemplate, /*$it,*/ $domDocument, $xpath, $templateName) {

    foreach ($xpath->query('.//comment()', $domTemplateContainer) as $domComment) {
        $domComment->parentNode->removeChild($domComment);
    }

    foreach ($xpath->query('.//tpl-static', $domTemplateContainer) as $domStatic) {
        foreach ($domStatic->childNodes as $curChildNode) {
            //$it->_domDocumentHead->appendChild($curChildNode->cloneNode(true));
        }
        $domStatic->parentNode->removeChild($domStatic);
    }
};

$adoptTemplate($domDocumentFragment);

// FAIL!
/*foreach ($xpath->query('.//text()[normalize-space() = ""]', $domDocumentFragment) as $domNode) {
    $domNode->parentNode->removeChild($domNode);
}*/
// HERE IS 
// workaround...
foreach ($xpath->query('./descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]', $domDocumentFragment) as $domNode) {
    $domNode->parentNode->removeChild($domNode);
}

if ($domDocumentFragment->childNodes->length > 1) {
    throw new \Exception('Single node expected in template "' . $templateName . '", ' . $domDocumentFragment->childNodes->length . ' given.');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pure selection does not work? You are not simply selecting nodes, you are iterating the returned DOMNodeList and are manipulating the DOM tree while iterating. As usual DOM collections are live collections the manipulation of the tree while iterating a node list requires special care, like iterating from the end if you want to remove nodes. Can you show a minimal input snippet for which your code fails, together with precise description as to which nodes are not removed?

Comment: xpath result is not live. anyway the workaround query works correctly but still loops are the same. so reason is in query processing. the question is why the difference takes place.

Comment: also - no problems with element nodes. only XML-comment and XML-text types affected.

Comment: The node type is not the problem. However whitespace nodes might be added be the auto formatter. Fetching and removing the nodes works fine without the explicit axis. https://eval.in/626410 You will need to debug your source to find the error.

Comment: The code i've added to the question indicates the result is different. Formatter doesn't affect things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped down you code to test different expressions.

```
$xml = '
<tpl-static>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/icon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/html5reset-1.6.1.css" />
</tpl-static>
<br/>
';

$domDocument = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$domDocumentFragment = $domDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$domDocumentFragment->appendXml($xml);

$expressions = [
  './/text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './*/text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './*/descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]'
];

foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
  $nodes = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $domDocumentFragment);
  var_dump($expression, $nodes->length);
}
```

Output:

```
string(33) ".//text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(3)
string(34) "./*/text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(3)
string(52) "./descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(6)
string(54) "./*/descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(3)
```

As you can see the first two expressions return the same node count while the third (your workaround) returns a larger number. It looks like the first expression does not include the direct text child nodes of the fragment.

I modified the source to include an top level element that can be used as the context for the expressions.

```
$xml = '<foo>
<tpl-static>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/icon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/html5reset-1.6.1.css" />
</tpl-static>
<br/>
</foo>';

$domDocument = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$domDocumentFragment = $domDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$domDocumentFragment->appendXml($xml);
$context = $domDocumentFragment->firstChild;

$expressions = [
  './/text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './*/text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]',
  './*/descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]'
];

foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
  $nodes = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $context);
  var_dump($expression, $nodes->length);
}
```

Output:

```
string(33) ".//text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(6)
string(34) "./*/text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(3)
string(52) "./descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(6)
string(54) "./*/descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space() = ""]"
int(3)
```

This returns the expected result. The first expression now includes the direct child nodes of the context.

It looks like `.//text()` is interpreted differently if the context node is an document fragment.

You might think that a bug, but according to the W3C spec [a fragment is not a valid context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-XPath-20040226/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) for an Xpath expression.

> If the XPathEvaluator was obtained by casting the Document then this must be owned by the same document and must be a Document, Element, Attribute, Text, CDATASection, Comment, ProcessingInstruction, or XPathNamespace node.

So to make your source conform to the spec, you would have to iterate the child nodes and evaluate the expression for each node. In this case `descendant-or-self::text()` would work in a deterministic way.

Comment: "and must be a Document, ..." - it is not closed list though, there is no mentions like "only Document, Element, ...". Anyway this inconsistency with DocumentFragment lookes like a bug as for me. Okay.